# Mapping JSON Array to Java POJO

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, gson

How would i map this JSON to an object?

```
{"d":"[{\"Key\":\"3\",\"ExternalKey\":\"143234A\",\"Name\":\"cup of juice\",\"Litres\":\"2 litres\",\"Date\":\"2016-10-06T08:32:27\",\"Capacity\":5.4900,\"CapacityType\":\"%\"}, {\"Key\":\"3\",\"ExternalKey\":\"143234A\",\"Name\":\"cup of milk\",\"Litres\":\"2.4 litres\",\"Date\":\"2016-10-06T08:32:27\",\"Capacity\":1667.6100,\"CapacityType\":\"M\"}]"}
```

I've tried using a HashMap but it just puts "d" as the string and the rest as a String object with one element

Comment: define a class matching the json structure

Comment: I have, still doesn't map it properly

Comment: it gives me this error : com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token at [Source: {"d":"[{\"Key\":\"3\"...... etc

Answer (score 0):

Your Json string has some extra " characters.

This is the final json:

```
{
  "d": [
    {
      "Key": "3",
      "ExternalKey": "143234A",
      "Name": "cup of juice",
      "Litres": "2 litres",
      "Date": "2016-10-06T08:32:27",
      "Capacity": 5.49,
      "CapacityType": "%"
    },
    {
      "Key": "3",
      "ExternalKey": "143234A",
      "Name": "cup of milk",
      "Litres": "2.4 litres",
      "Date": "2016-10-06T08:32:27",
      "Capacity": 1667.61,
      "CapacityType": "M"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now you can copy the json and paste it [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to get the pojo.

Comment: I've done that but it gives me this error : 

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token
 at [Source: {"d":"[{\"Key\":\"3\"...... etc

Comment: As I said you have some extra " in your json string, which means that those extra " should not be there to make it work. I hope you can understand

Comment: Hi Nongthonbam, i can't see where the extra " are, they seem to be in the right places (e.g all the values are strings except for Capacity, so they are enclosed in ".  Where are the extra " ?

Comment: There's no extra ", if i substring out the "d" key and map it as a JSON Array it works, that'll have to be the solution for now...

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely common problem known as data marshaling. In java, Jackson is the general best solution. Read this tutorial: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Comment: I've tried Jackson and Gson, both of which don't map it correctly

Comment: it gives me this error : com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token at [Source: {"d":"[{\"Key\":\"3\"...... etc

Comment: if i substring out the "d" key and map it as a JSON Array it works, that'll have to be the solution for now...

Answer (score 0):

```
There are n numbers of libraries available for parsing the JSON and convert into in java classes.

Some of the examples are,

GSON
Jackson
Logan Square
Moshi, etc

You need to create a java class which map with your JSON Response and need to change your pojo according to parsing library.

For Example, 

Using Logan Square you must annotate your POJO class to @JsonObject and all properties must be annotated with @JsonField.

Now, you can parse your json using method 

...
LoganSquare.parse(jsonString, pojoClassName);
...

Hopefully this will help you.

Cheers
```

Comment: Hi Amit, not sure if you read the posts above before commenting but i've already tried this, it doesn't work for this JSON response

Answer (score 0):

if i substring out the "d" key and map it as a JSON Array it works, that'll have to be the solution for now...